# Anaconda3 using JupyterNotebook; ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Quantlib'

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, quantlib

I have installed Anaconda Navigator and launched JupyterNotebook
I have also verified that Quantlib has been installed - both in JupyterNotebook and via the 'cmd' prompt on my PC.

However, when I try to run [import Quantlib as ql] in JupyterNotebook, I get a ModuleNotFoundError. Why is this happening, and what can I do to fix it?

The version of Python installed on my local drive is 3.8.8, but Jupyter Notebook says 3.7.4 when I try to check which version is being run (not sure if this is relevant information?)

I am working in Windows, and old Microsoft 2007 software.

[Attached image of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8hKe.png)

Thanks in advance for your help,
Tlhogi

Comment: Please post the error as text, not an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package name is QuantLib with a capital L, not Quantlib, so`import QuantLib as ql` should work.